# What happened with HTTP package in Dart 2.1?

Tags: http, dart, package, flutter

With dart 2.0 and lower I was able to import the HTTP package directly without modifying my pubspec.yaml file.

I've opened an old project and I've got the error:
"Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.
That library is in a package that is not known. Maybe you forgot to mention it in your pubspec.yaml file?"

I had to go to pubpect.yaml file, and under dependencies I've added: "http: ^0.12.0" to make my project work again.

What happened, why was the HTTP package removed from dart core libraries?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Changelog#v025

> ### v0.2.5
>
> [#15416](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/15565) removed package:http from Flutter and replaced all usages with the HttpClient from dart:io. If you use package:http you must add it
>   as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml to continue using it.

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Changelog#v025

Answer (score 3):

As the flutter has removed the http from dart.io, you can't directly use it without specifying the dependency in pubspec.yaml file.
open the flutter project and add the http library dependency as given below,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"
  http: ^0.12.0
```